# How to turn a json object into individual rows

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a "rules" column that looks like this:

```
{"111_abc":0,"222_def":0,"333_abs":0}
```

I'd like to write a postgres query to turn this into something like this:

```
rules
111_abc
222_def
333_abs
```

I have tried several renditions of json_extract_path or json_array_element - no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`jsonb_object_keys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(rules) as (
values
    ('{"111_abc":0,"222_def":0,"333_abs":0}'::jsonb)
)

select jsonb_object_keys(rules) as rules
from my_table;

  rules  
---------
 111_abc
 222_def
 333_abs
(3 rows)
```

Comment: awesome - thank you. I'm betting this works, but I just realized I'm pulling from a datawarehouse that uses postgres version 8.0.2. I don't think json data types were introduced until version 9.2. I'll either have to work on updating the sql version, or find a way to write a udf.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from json_each_text('{"111_abc":0,"222_def":0,"333_abs":0}')
```